# Display units of measure for a product

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart2.x

Good day. Please help me to display units of measurement for goods. OcStore 2.3 engine.
By default, units of measurement are not displayed next to the product, they helped me to display them on the product page in this way:

In

*catalog/model/catalog/product.php*

Find line:

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
```

Before the line mentioned above add the following code:

```
public function getProductWeightWithUnit($product_id) {
    $product_info = $this->getProduct($product_id);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT unit FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description` WHERE 
    weight_class_id='".$product_info['weight_class_id']."'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        return number_format($product_info['weight'],2) . " " . $query->row['unit'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Save changes and close the file.

Now, open file

*catalog/controller/product/product.php*

Find line:

```
if ($product_info['minimum']) {
```

Before the line mentioned above add the following code:

```
if ($product_info['weight']) {
     $data['weight'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductWeightWithUnit($this->request->get['product_id']);
} else {
     $data['weight'] = false;
}
```

Now, the backend code is ready. Based on the theme that you use, you need to edit the correct product.tpl file from your theme. For example if you use the default theme, then the file to edit is the following:

*catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl*

Find the line:

```
<li><?php echo $text_stock; ?> <?php echo $stock; ?></li>
```

and add the following code after:

```
<li><?php echo $weight; ?></li>
```

Fine! Everything works on the product page. But you need it to work the same in modules (for example Featured Products).

I do all the same steps for the module

Backend:

*catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php*

and front end:

*catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/featured.tpl*

But I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: product_id in C:\OSPanel\domains\mywebsite.com\catalog\controller\extension\module\featured.php on line 43
```

That's what it says:

```
    if ($product_info['weight']) {
LINE 43     $data['weight'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductWeightWithUnit($this->request->get['product_id']);
    } else {
        $data['weight'] = false;
    }
```

Why not seen `product_id` in ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php*.

Find

```
if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
```

Add before

```
if ($product_info['weight']) {
    $weight = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductWeightWithUnit($product_info['product_id']);
} else {
    $weight = false;
}
```

Basically, here I've replaced `$this->request->get['product_id']` with `$product_info['product_id']`, like @K.B. said in his answer, but made more accurate example.

Then, in the same file find

```
'tax'         => $tax,
```

Add after

```
'weight'      => $weight,
```

Now go to *catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/featured.tpl*

Find

```
<?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
<span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Add after

```
<?php if ($product['weight']) { ?>
<span><?php echo $product['weight']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes your are right, the best way to give the whole answer instead to put the coder on the way...

Comment: @focus.style thank! Now there is no error! But is weight displayed instead of units? How do I add a unit of measurement?

Comment: I'm sorry. there was a mistake in code. Updated the answer, replaced `$data['weight']` with `$weight`. Just tested. Now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `$product_info['product_id']` or just `$product_id`  instead `$this->request->get['product_id']` Because you can't get product_id's for several products using this expression, which are in this loop `foreach ($products as $product_id) {`